# blogger post share wrong title on Google Plus

Tags: share, google-plus, blogger

I connected my blog with Google plus, so that when I publish a new post on blogger there is a Google plus pop up to share that post on Google plus.

But I have a problem when I share a post on Google plus it also shares the blog title along with the post title, this looks ugly. I want to just share the post title not with blog title.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing how Blogger displays Title of your posts.

Last year I wrote a [post](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2012/05/blogger-change-page-title-to-increase-traffic/) on my blog describing how to do that in Blogger, just skip to the second part of the post.

Basically in your template locate this line:

```
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
```

and replace it with

```
<title>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageName== ""'>
<data:blog.title/>
<b:else/>
<data:blog.pageName/>
</b:if>
</title>
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply friend but after implementing this my above mention problem not solved. :(    it still share my blog title along with post title on Google plus sharing.

Comment: On your browser, what is the title of your post (the one you want to share)? Does it still include both Blog title and Post title? You could also just provide me with the link, so I can check.

Comment: check this is my actual blog post  http://www.roshantv.in/2013/03/express-news-live-streaming.html         but after sharing this post on Google plus it looks as on Google plus  check this http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kASuM2JQdPE/UU6l0wsUg7I/AAAAAAAAAOk/nbnwwaSE0Ec/s1600/exp.jpg

Comment: Try replacing title code in your template with <title>
<data:blog.pageName/>
</title> - I want to check what title your homepage and that page above will have.